# How to Call Webservice from Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin

**(ADDON: I thought that if i use Emulator on the same computer that the localhost would work)**

Hi I have googled around and looked on videos for hours and see them succeed with this but i cant get it to work.

I notice that you cant do direct connection to a external SqlDB from Xamarin.Android
You have to make your own webservice for this solution.

i have created a webservice and just left the helloworld() that returns a string.

```
public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

And Xamarin.Android need to have it on a IIS cant be reached by a IIS express. 
Checked i have it there and i go into the IIS and test it, it apear and works good. I get the WDSL from it

http://localhost/Webservicedemo/Connector.asmx?WSDL

Then i go into my Xamarin.Android projekt and try to present it.
I have done the 
**Add web reference** 
on the Xamarin.Android project and it apers.

**want to achieve:**
Print put "helloworld" into my textview

But when i write this.
PS: I called the referens **(GetResultFromDB)** , **Connector** is the *.cs File

```
    TextView textfält = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textviewPrintout);           

    try
    {
        GetResultFromDB.Connector result = new GetResultFromDB.Connector();              
        String test = result.HelloWorld();
        textfält.Text = test;
}
    catch (Exception a) {

        textfält.Text = "DATA " + a.Data + 
            "\n" + "HResult " + a.HResult + 
            "\nMessage " + a.Message + 
            "\nSource " + a.Source + 
            "HelpLink " + a.HelpLink +
            "\nInnerException" + a.InnerException;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `http://localhost/Webservice....` Are you using `localhost` within your Android code? If so that is not your hosting PC, but the emulator or device itself...

Comment: do you know what `localhost` means?

Comment: You may need to call it inside await. Try the code inside this  

   `await Task.Run(() => {`
    
                    `});`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes.

Comment: so you are aware that trying to connect to `localhost` you are trying to connect to the device itself, which obviously is not running the web service?

Comment: Thougt that it was different if it was a emulator on the same PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer was:**

To take the ip of the computer and replace the localhost. 
And it worked